# Assign a unique value to consecutive null values untill a non value

Tags: python, pandas, null

I want to apply a function that does the cumulative count of null values.

The closest solution I came to was this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create the column
col = pd.Series([1, 2, np.nan, np.nan, 3, 4, np.nan, np.nan, 5])

col.isnull().cumsum()
```

But the output is not the way I want:

```
0    0
1    0
2    1
3    2
4    2
5    2
6    3
7    4
8    4
dtype: int32
```

I want the output to be the following: [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2].

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want to count only the first NA per stretch:

```
m = col.isna()
out = (m & ~m.shift(fill_value=False)).cumsum()
```

Shortcut:

```
m = col.isna()
out = (m & m.diff()).cumsum()
```

Output:

```
0    0
1    0
2    1
3    1
4    1
5    1
6    2
7    2
8    2
dtype: int64
```

Intermediates:

```
   col      m  ~m.shift(fill_value=False)      &  cumsum
0  1.0  False                        True  False       0
1  2.0  False                        True  False       0
2  NaN   True                        True   True       1
3  NaN   True                       False  False       1
4  3.0  False                       False  False       1
5  4.0  False                        True  False       1
6  NaN   True                        True   True       2
7  NaN   True                       False  False       2
8  5.0  False                       False  False       2
```

Variant:

```
out = col.isna().astype(int).diff().eq(1).cumsum()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
# Increment when the previous row is not n/a AND the current row is n/a
out = (col.shift().notna() & col.isna()).cumsum()
print(out)

# Output
0    0
1    0
2    1
3    1
4    1
5    1
6    2
7    2
8    2
dtype: int64
```